# How to reproduce the equivalent of a Countif excel function in Business Objects?

Tags: excel, countif, business-objects, equivalent

I'm from France (sorry for my english) and I am currently working on the latest version of Business Objects (business-intelligence suite from SAP).
I would like to transpose an Excel formula to Business Objects, but I cannot. Could someone be able to answer me how to reproduce the equivalent of a Countif function, please ?
In my example, I have a whole list of repeating social security numbers to which I have appended a variable number taken from another field. I would like to do a count for each security number and know how many of them have the "2" value attached to them in my other field.


Example :

For 1741111111100 | 17411111111001, the result in a new field will be 2.

For 1741111111100 | 17411111111001, the result in a new field will be 2.

For 1741111111100 | 17411111111002, the result in a new field will be 2.

For 1741111111100 | 17411111111002, the result in a new field will be 2.

For 1741111111100 | 17411111111003, the result in a new field will be 2.

For 1751111111100 | 17511111111001, the result in a new field will be 1.

For 1751111111100 | 17511111111002, the result in a new field will be 1.

For 1751111111100 | 17511111111003, the result in a new field will be 1.

For 1761111111100 | 17611111111001, the result in a new field will be 0.

For 1761111111100 | 17611111111001, the result in a new field will be 0.

For 1761111111100 | 17611111111003, the result in a new field will be 0.

In excel it's easy to do with a Countif function but how could I do this in Business Objects, please ?
Thank you in advance because I spent a whole afternoon in vain.


**RE-EDIT**

Here's the same example with excel :


1741111111100|1|17411111111001|2|

1741111111100|1|17411111111001|2|

1741111111100|2|17411111111002|2|

1741111111100|2|17411111111002|2|

1741111111100|3|17411111111003|2|

1751111111100|1|17511111111001|1|

1751111111100|2|17511111111002|1|

1751111111100|3|17511111111003|1|

1761111111100|1|17611111111001|0|

1761111111100|1|17611111111001|0|

1761111111100|3|17611111111003|0|


A column :

there are my security numbers (1741111111100 repeated 5 times, 1751111111100 repeated 3 times, 1761111111100 repeated 3 times)

B column :

It's a number between 1 and 3.

C column :

I concatenated A column + B column like =CONCATENATE(A1;B1)

D column :

Here are my countif functions done like this :

=COUNTIF(C$1:C$11;CONCATENATE(A1;"2")) that gives a quantity of "2".

=COUNTIF(C$1:C$11;CONCATENATE(A2;"2")) that gives a quantity of "2".

=COUNTIF(C$1:C$11;CONCATENATE(A3;"2")) that gives a quantity of "2".

=COUNTIF(C$1:C$11;CONCATENATE(A4;"2")) that gives a quantity of "2".

=COUNTIF(C$1:C$11;CONCATENATE(A5;"2")) that gives a quantity of "2".

=COUNTIF(C$1:C$11;CONCATENATE(A6;"2")) that gives a quantity of "1".

=COUNTIF(C$1:C$11;CONCATENATE(A7;"2")) that gives a quantity of "1".

=COUNTIF(C$1:C$11;CONCATENATE(A8;"2")) that gives a quantity of "1".

=COUNTIF(C$1:C$11;CONCATENATE(A9;"2")) that gives a quantity of "0".

=COUNTIF(C$1:C$11;CONCATENATE(A10;"2")) that gives a quantity of "0".

=COUNTIF(C$1:C$11;CONCATENATE(A11;"2")) that gives a quantity of "0".

I was interested by the "2" value attached to the security number and the number of security numbers concerned by this attachment.

So, it's easy to do with excel but so so so hard to do with B.I. !

Thanx for any help.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand your example.  Perhaps providing the example from excel would help clarify what you are attempting to do

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, I presented my problem in an unclear fashion. I add the equivalent with excel.

Comment: That helped.  Thanks.    Basically I think you're after `=Sum(If([C]=[Concat];1;0)) ForEach([Concat]) In ([C])`  full detail in answer

Answer (score 0):

**Background:**
Context Operators:

- ForEach
- ForAll
- In

Operate on "Sets" of data allowing you to parse out data into subsets and aggregate.  in SQL this is similar to "Over Partition By" if you're familiar with it.

**Answer:**
If we assume you create a variable in the report [Concat] as follows:

```
=Concatenation([A];"2")
```

Then we can use formula:

```
=Sum(If([C]=[Concat];1;0)) ForEach([Concat]) In ([C])
```

Where [C] is your concatenated columns A+B.

**Explanation**
The above essentially says if [C] = [Concat] return a 1 otherwise return a 0 and then sum the results of those evaluations together.

This occurs ForEach unique value within [Concat]; found in [C].

Logically the system finds all the unique values in [Concat] in then iterates though [C] evaluating if [C]=[Concat] for each case.  it then sums the results for each [concat] and then renders those results for each [C]

**Additional Point:**
In my example the report data was being "combined" due to duplicate values So row 1, row 2 in your example were combined.  I had to turn off BO's combining of this row data or my results were skewed.  This can be accomplished by formatting the result table and checking the top checkbox "Avoid Duplicate row Aggregation"  If you have other values which make each row unique, you will not have this problem.  You can turn this off at a query level as well in the query properties of the edit data provider.  I believe it depends on what source you use as to which method  must be used... But I'm not positive.

So below you can see results from [Cnt] match your expected results in column D using the aforementioned formula.

[image]

Comment: There likely is a way to do this with `count()`, but I ran out of play time to look at it further

Comment: Thanx a lot for your answer which is precise, clear and illustrated. Never mind the method, this one is exactly what I was trying to do ! I've been looking at stackoverflow for VBA (for both Excel and Access) for years. I didn't think Business Objects was popular enough that I could be helped. Thanks a lot ! Jeff from Bordeaux, France.

Comment: @jeff33france  Glad to be of service.  If testing is complete and this solutions does prove to meet your needs, please accept the answer so the question can be deemed closed.  I've recently started monitoring the Business Objects Tag more having been involved in Business Objects for a few years now.  So I try to chime in when It's something I think I can answer.